# How to return data calculated in a promise to the controller that ultimately triggered the promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, promise

I do a bulk insert of documents that is initiated by a call to the function, `addNewFeedToUserFeeds`. `addNewFeedToUserFeeds` is called from a controller and, I'd like it to return the docs created by the bulk insert function in `insertIntoDB`, to that controller. However, it seems that because the bulk insert happens inside a promise, the results of that insert are lost. Is there a way to do this that I am missing?

```
const discover = require('rssdiscovery');
const FeedParser = require('feedparser');
const request = require('request');
const UserFeedEntryMap = require('../models/userFeedEntryMap');

(function () {

  let currentuser = {};

  function insertIntoDB(dataFromFeed) {

    const loop = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const ufmObjects = [];

      dataFromFeed.forEach((item) => {

        const feed = {
          title: item.meta.title,
          description: item.meta.description,
          lastUpdate: item.meta.date, // most recent update
          link: item.meta.link,
          xmlUrl: item.meta.xmlUrl
        };

        const feedEntry = {
          title: item.title,
          link: item.link,
          description: item.description,
          summary: item.summary,
          author: item.author,
          pubdate: item.pubDate,
          date: item.date,
          guid: item.guid,
          image: item.image.url,
          categories: item.categories,
          source: item.source,
        };

        const ufem = new UserFeedEntryMap({
          user_name: currentuser.local.userName,
          feed_entry_metaData: feed,
          feed_entry: feedEntry
        });

        ufmObjects.push(ufem);

      });
      resolve(ufmObjects);
    });

    loop.then((ufmObjects) => {
      UserFeedEntryMap.insertMany(ufmObjects, (error, docs) => {
        if (error) {
          console.log(error);
        } else {
          console.log(docs);
        }
      });
    });
  }

  function parseFeedToObjects(xmlURL) {
    const feedItems = [];
    const req = request(xmlURL);
    const feedparser = new FeedParser();

    req.on('error', (error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });

    req.on('response', function (res) {
      const stream = this;
      if (res.statusCode !== 200) {
        this.emit('error', new Error('Bad status code'));
      } else {
        stream.pipe(feedparser);
      }
    });

    feedparser.on('error', (error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });

    feedparser.on('readable', function () {
      const stream = this;
      const meta = this.meta;
      let item;

      while (item = stream.read()) {
        feedItems.push(item);
      }
    });

    feedparser.on('end', () => {
      // emit error if no items
    //   console.log(feedItems);
      insertIntoDB(feedItems);
    });

  }


  exports.addNewFeedToUserFeeds = function name(user, url) {
    currentuser = user;
    discover(url, (err, results) => {
      const baseURL = url.slice(0, -1);
      parseFeedToObjects(results.links.length > 1 ? results.links[0].href : baseURL + results.links[0].href);
    });
  };
}());
```

Comment: Why is `insertIntoDB` using a Promise at all? Pushing objects into an array isn't asynchronous. The only asynchronous task is `.insertMany()` which doesn't return a Promise but uses a callback.

Comment: @Andreas. How would I defer the call to insertMany until all the items were pushed to the array?

Comment: @Andreas, I see now. Looks like everything stops until the foreach is completed, like you said.

Comment: However, even after removing the promise, I'm still having a problem sending the docs back to the controller.

Comment: Thanks @Andreas, I've worked out an answer with you initial comments. I'll post it now.

Comment: Why is `loop` even a promise? You don't appear to do anything asynchronous inside that `new Promise`

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to be using [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) for returning the results of multiple asynchronous processes. It will give you an array of all of the results and will wait until all processes are completed before resolving.